# SET @tmpYr - declared as INT

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble casting this variable.. I tried casting & converting and I am getting no where..

Can you please assists

```
DECLARE @tmpYr INT;
DECLARE @tDate1 CHAR(10);


SET @tmpYr = DATEPART(YEAR,(DATEADD(yyyy, -1,  @tmpDate1 ))));
```

Comment: You might describe what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results would be hlepful.

Comment: What is `@tmpDate1`? `@tmpDate1` = `@tDate1` and = some date value like '2015-12-17'?

Comment: tmpDate1 is char(20)  in which its basically set to the beginning of the prior month. So its set to 11/1/2015... SO tmpYr =  taking out the year from tmpDate1... then subtracting 1 year. hopefully this helps explain..  getting a conversion error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your code and added some example, please try it

```
DECLARE @tmpYr INT;
DECLARE @tDate1 CHAR(10);
SET @tDate1 = '2015-12-17'

SET @tmpYr = DATEPART(YEAR,(DATEADD(yyyy, -1,  @tDate1 )))
select @tmpYr
```

If you need to get value of `year - 1` then you can try simple solution like `SET @tmpYr = YEAR(@tDate1) - 1`

Comment: Thanks MegaTron,  I forgot to add :  SET @tmpDate1 = '11 /*@tMth*/ /1/2015' /*@tYear*/  .... Apparently the /*@tMth*/ was causing the issue.. Once i deleted that part and made it '11/1/2015' it worked fine. Thanks, guys...  If you can provide an explanation on this issue i would appreciate it!